# Django FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME in settings

Tags: django

i am struggling to find information what the below code does:

```
if set_prefix:
        set_script_prefix(
            '/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is None else settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME
        )
```

What are thread local-url resolvers scripts?
Is it setting the prefix of those scripts?
What significance does it have, does it have something to do with configuration of webservers and environmental variables?

```
from django.utils.version import get_version

VERSION = (3, 0, 1, 'alpha', 1)

__version__ = get_version(VERSION)


[docs]def setup(set_prefix=True):
    """
    Configure the settings (this happens as a side effect of accessing the
    first setting), configure logging and populate the app registry.
    Set the thread-local urlresolvers script prefix if `set_prefix` is True.
    """
    from django.apps import apps
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.urls import set_script_prefix
    from django.utils.log import configure_logging

    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
    if set_prefix:
        set_script_prefix(
            '/' if settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME is None else settings.FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME
        )
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#force-script-name) doesn't say much but says:

> this will be used as the value of the SCRIPT_NAME environment variable in any HTTP request

What I understood is that it's a variable that can contain the global path of the root of scripts used by some scripts. If needed it can be set in settings.py.

In my case I got a warning message from Swagger (drf_yasg):

```
path component of api base URL https://example.com/ is ignored; use FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME instead
```

To solve this little problem I made the following settings:
**urls.py** (api):

```
schema_view = get_schema_view(
openapi.Info(
  title="Super API",
  default_version='v1',
  description="",
  terms_of_service="https://example.com/terms-of-service/",
  contact=openapi.Contact(email="dev@example.com"),
  license=openapi.License(name="BSD License"),
  ),
  url='https://example.com',   # <========
  public=True,
  permission_classes=(permissions.AllowAny,),
  )
```

**Settings.py**:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/'
```

Which results in no longer having this warning and having Swagger displays the correct base url.

[image]

Hoping this will help.